# How far apart should nails be when installing baseboards?

Tags: baseboard

I am using a nail/brad gun to install baseboard.  How far should I space the nails?  I want to make sure I hit some of the studs, but don't want to take the time to find exactly where all the studs are, so it seems better to space them a little closer.

Comment: Find 1 stud then measure 16" on center (usually) to hit the rest of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We usually tack the baseboard in place with one nail at each side, and then find the studs with a stud sensor, marking on the baseboard as we go.

Alternately, I would think that every 12 inches would be sufficient. We also caulk the top of the baseboards with paintable latex caulk (which helps with dusting later), and that helps hold the baseboard to the wall too.

With shoe moulding (which I seriously recommend, especially on 2nd stories and pier on beam structures), it doesn't matter since the nails go into the baseboard first.

Answer (score 1):

If you nail near the bottom, you can usually hit the horozontal boards under the studs in the wall and therefore can put nails anywhere. I would just put them every 16 inches or 2 feet. I would recommend using a stud finder to find the studs to nail near the top of the board. Once you find one stud, you know to look every 16 inches from it.

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends on the height of the baseboard. Small stuff you can get by with nailing on the bottom 2X4 along the wall. In that case every 16 to 24"- enough to make it hold tight to the wall without movement. If you have an old house with lots of irregularities in the floors or walls, it will require more attention and that may be another discussion all together. 
Large baseboard (like 3 1/4 - 5 1/4" will require also hitting the studs along the way a few inches up. I would hit every 16" on top with about every 24" on bottom as long as you know you are hitting the bottom plate.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when the old base is off you can usually see if there are nails in the bottom of the sheet rock messure those to see if the 16 on center if they are figure how high your trim is the mark ur studs right above where ur caulk will go to cover the mark.